# Customize catch block in Java and enable smart insert in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, try-catch, customization

In Eclipse when we select code statements and right click on it, it gives us an option for surrounding with `try/catch` block, after selecting this option our code looks like.

```
try {
    //selected code lines
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I want to define a custom catch block which should look like below after selecting surround with `try/catch` block from eclipse smart insert:

```
try {
    //selected code lines
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    myCustomLogger.LogMe(Log.getStackTraceString(e));
}
```

Is it possible?

Does Eclipse allow us to customize some properties for specific project in smart insert?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's possible, open Eclipse Preference and then **`Java > Code Style > Code Templates`**. There you select **`Code > Catch block body`**. Here you can edit your `try/catch` block.

Add `myCustomLogger.LogMe(Log.getStackTraceString(${exception_var}));`

[image]